# Responsive and split layout

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, responsive

I started a project with [react-splitter-layout](https://github.com/zesik/react-splitter-layout) and [material ui](https://material-ui.com/) library.

I would like to find a way to create responsive components, with material ui Grid or Box component

I encounter a problem with responsive, I would like my left panel to be responsive (use of xs / md / lg) with Grid component based on the size of the container (not window size), as you can see in the example below , this is not the case. It's use the viewport size. (I know it's normal because of media queries).

Here the code sample : https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-i04rr?file=/demo.js (recommended to open the rendering in a new tab to see the problem)

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import SplitterLayout from "react-splitter-layout";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: "center",
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary
  }
}));

export default function CenteredGrid() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <SplitterLayout>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs={4} md={6} lg={8}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={4} md={4} lg={2}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={4} md={2} lg={2}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
      <div>Panel 2</div>
    </SplitterLayout>
  );
}
```

Anyone have a solution to this problem ?

Best regards,

**EDIT**
I also posted in material ui github https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/25189

Answer (score 1):

This is one of my question when I started using material-UI or any CSS framework.

Material-UI currently supports almost cases you need especially for responsive, and I never use any other library/framework for responsive. First, you know that all `xs`, `sm`, `md` are based on screen size, not on their container.

Then, the problem here is how did you called a "container"? When you work with material-UI, you should layout everything based on screen size instead of a specific container. Because your "container" you are think about doesn't have any meaning in responsive. It just help you solve the layout problem.

To be honest, just change your mind, thinking in the way of Material-UI, and everything about responsive become easily.

Comment: What I call a parent container in this case is everything in the left panel
`<div className = {classes.root}>… </div>`
In my project the user can open/close the right panel like a sidebar/drawer with a button located on the topbar. So, everything on the left should be responsive.(When sidebar is closed the container == screen size)
Just like on the **codesandbox UI**, they have a code part and a rendered part, the rendering is displayed inside an iframe and when you dragging in the middle the content adapts to different devices. I would like something similar but without  using an iframe.

Comment: Okay, I see. If you want to achieve that, you will need another container solution like [react-grid-layout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout), and you CAN NOT use `xs`/`sm`/etc, you NEED to define breakpoints for that container yourself. Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, currently I already use a library [react-container-query](https://github.com/react-container-query/react-container-query) and I wanted to be sure that there was no other alternative.

Comment: Yes, `react-container-query` is a nice library also :)